# How to run rspec without deprecated warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to follow "[Getting Started with RSpec — Part 1](https://medium.com/@mindovermiles262/getting-started-with-rspec-part-1-9418909f5e53)", however, whenever I try to run

```
rspec
```

I receive:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:29: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:30: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0/specifications/raspell-1.3.gemspec:20.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated

An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: return gem_original_require(path)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- spec_helper
# /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
# /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2103:in `load_file_handling_errors'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1565:in `block in requires='
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1565:in `each'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1565:in `requires='
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:113:in `block in process_options_into'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `each'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `process_options_into'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:132:in `configure'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
# /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
# /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
# 
#   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
#   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
#   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00004 seconds (files took 0.06007 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

I am new to Rspec. I checked `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

However, `gem -v` results in:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:29: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:30: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/dnsruby-1.54.gemspec:17.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/erubis-2.7.0.gemspec:17.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/image_science-1.2.2.gemspec:20.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/net-http-persistent-2.9.4.gemspec:20.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0/specifications/raspell-1.3.gemspec:20.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/snmp-1.2.0.gemspec:18.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:29: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:30: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
3.1.3
```

I tried to install Nokogiri and to fix the `Gem::ConfigMap` deprecated issue but nothing seemed to work.

How should I run the tests?

Comment: Do you have a `spec_helper.rb` in the right directory?

Comment: It sounds like you have a `.rspec` file that tries to require `spec_helper` which you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

For some time now I have had problems loading my "calculator_spec.rb" test with or without "spec_helper", this tutorial that you showed "Introduction to RSpec - Part 1" is very easy. This problem is not in the spec_helper, if you follow the steps, but in how you are writing in your text editor. I use the sublime, try not to give Ctrl + C - V, type the code because quotes, spaces can be interpreted differently afterwards in the interpreter.
As for the deprecated gem, you are using rspec version 3.1, your post is not as old as the current version 3.9, do not specify the version in Gemfile as it will automatically install the latest version.

Recommendations:
Use a newer version of ruby.
Preferably using an RVM.
Follow the tutorial presented, without copying and pasting, for now do nothing beyond the scope. (There is no installation of spec_helper).